# how to execute a custom copy command in linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, copy, putty, cp

i have to move some files from a directory to another one, but this is a bit tricky.

here is my folder structure

```
/var/www/media_test1/media001/001_pm_001.jpg
                              th001_pm_001.jpg

/var/www/media_test1/media002/002_pm_001.jpg
                              th002_pm_001.jpg

/var/www/media_test1/media003/003_pm_001.jpg
                              th003_pm_001.jpg

/var/www/media_test1/media004/004_pm_001.jpg
                              th004_pm_001.jpg
```

i basically want to move the pictures from each folder that do not have `th` into another directory like this:

```
/var/www/media_test2/media001/001_pm_001.jpg
/var/www/media_test2/media002/002_pm_001.jpg
/var/www/media_test2/media003/003_pm_001.jpg
/var/www/media_test2/media004/004_pm_001.jpg
```

what i am thinking is to create a list of the images i want to move by using s `ls` command to list all pictures + their path that don't have `th` -> export that to a file -> build a `cp` command like:

```
cp /var/www/media_test1/media001/001_pm_001.jpg /var/www/media_test2/media001/001_pm_001.jpg
cp /var/www/media_test1/media002/002_pm_001.jpg /var/www/media_test2/media001/002_pm_002.jpg
...
```

then execute the command.

the problem is that i don't know how to write these commands.

Is there a better way of doing this? any ideas on what commands i can use?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the find command to do that. Make sure the destination directory exists and then run:

```
find /var/www/media_test1/media001/ -type f -not -name "th*" -exec cp {} /var/www/media_test2/media001/ \;
```

That will find all files that don't begin with "th" and copy them to /var/www/media_test2/media001/.

Comment: i have lots of folders. i need somehow to find all this paths like `/var/www/media_test1/media001/file` and `/var/www/media_test1/media002/file` and save them to a file first so i can build the `cp` command

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`mmv`](http://fclose.com/p/linux/man/1-mmv/) if you don't need it to be too flexible:

```
mmv '/var/www/media_test1/media???/???_pm_*.jpg' '/var/www/media_test2/media#1#2#3/#4#5#6_pm_#7.jpg'
```

This won't create the destination folders though; you will have to to that first.

If you need it to be more flexible, or create the destination folders for you the it would be better to write a script.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the `mv` command here. because you started off by saying "I have to move some files"... but you can just change it to `cp`... the structure is the same for both... The `|e` at the end of the `sed` expressions causes the sed-generated script to be automatically executed. You don't actually get to see the script, so I added it at the end of this post)...  The `mkdir -p` will check if the directory already exists and if it doesn't, then it makes it. If `mkdir` fails, the next command will not be executed.

```
# use `find' to get the main list of files.. 
# use `sed' to filter when both 'NNN's match in: /mediaNNN/NNN...
# `sed' also build and executes the *move* script

basepath1=/var/www/media_test1/
basepath2=/var/www/media_test2/

find $basepath1/media[0-9][0-9][0-9] \
      -type f -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9]*.jpg' |
sed -nr "
s|$basepath1(/media([0-9]{3})/)\2.*|\
mkdir -p \"$basepath2\1\" \&\&\n\
   mv -n \"&\" \\\\\n\
         \"$basepath2\1\"|e"
```

Here is the generated script

```
mkdir -p "/var/www/media_test2/media001/" &&
   mv -n "/var/www/media_test1/media001/001_pm_001.jpg" \
         "/var/www/media_test2/media001/"
mkdir -p "/var/www/media_test2/media002/" &&
   mv -n "/var/www/media_test1/media002/002_pm_001.jpg" \
         "/var/www/media_test2/media002/"
mkdir -p "/var/www/media_test2/media003/" &&
   mv -n "/var/www/media_test1/media003/003_pm_001.jpg" \
         "/var/www/media_test2/media003/"
mkdir -p "/var/www/media_test2/media004/" &&
   mv -n "/var/www/media_test1/media004/004_pm_001.jpg" \
         "/var/www/media_test2/media004/"
```